# Is it possible to have a rule which validates to ensure a class doesn't inherit from a specific class?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'd like to know if it's possible in SonarQube to have a rule that will validate a classes direct inheritance. We want to stop developers directly inheriting from a class in a library we don't control and use a wrapped class instead.

EDIT: The question was originally intended for `C#`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about Java, the configurable [Architectural constraint](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AArchitecturalConstraint) rule should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, looks like I didn't tag the question correctly with `C#` :). Is there something similar?

Comment: Sorry @JasonBert, the only option I see is to rewrite your app in Java. ;-p

Comment: I suspect that won't happen :)